# Cannot test "x in l" when l is a generator

Tags: python, algorithm, generator

#### Question

I am trying to understand the difference between a list comprehension and a generator expression:

```py
x = 25

if x in [i**2 for i in range(100)]:
    print('list version: {} is a square!'.format(x))
# list version: 25 is a square!

if x in (i**2 for i in range(100)):
    print('generator version: {} is a square!'.format(x))
# generator version: 25 is a square!
```

When called once, they both appear to do the same thing. So there isn't a difference?

But then I try them in a loop:

```py
l = [i**2 for i in range(100)]
g = (i**2 for i in range(100))

print('list version')
for x in range(20, 51):
    if x in l:
        print('{} is a square!'.format(x))
# list version
# 25 is a square!
# 36 is a square!
# 49 is a square!

print('generator version')
for x in range(20, 51):
    if x in g:
        print('{} is a square!'.format(x))
# generator version
#
```

In the generator version, no square is found. Why? What's different between a generator and a list?

#### Context

I am trying to solve the following problem: Given a number `n (n > 0)` I must produce the smallest square number `N (N > 0)` such that `n + N` is also a perfect square. If no response is received, return -1.

I have the following code:

```
def solve(n):
    # l = [i**2 for i in range(10**2)]
    l = (i**2 for i in range(10*4))
    r = -1
    for i in l:
        if n + i in l:
            return i
        else:
            r = -1
    return r
```

It works when I use list comprehension `l = [i**2 for i in range(10**2)]`, but not when I use generator `l = (i**2 for i in range(10*4)`.

I verified this code in Python visualizer and it does not enter the loop if I use the generating algorithm.

Could you please assist me?

Comment: What does " it doesn`t" mean?

Comment: it doesn`t worg with generetor

Comment: What details do you need to provide?
I'm new to this platform, maybe I forgot to indicate something

Comment: What does it do? How have you come to the conclusion that it doesn't enter the loop? Did you try `for i in l: print(i)` for example? What have you researched into solving it yourself? [ask]

Comment: You should mention what "doesn't work" means: does it produce the wrong output (which), does it produce an error (which), does it hang, ...etc. We expect that you provide debugging information.

Comment: Here is a post with a small help about how to describe a situation where something doesn't work: [What do you mean, "it doesn't work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work)

Comment: However, note that the elements in a generator are *generated* and *consumed* when they are looked at. Since you want to examine these elements repeatedly in a loop, you should probably store them in an appropriate data structure first. An appropriate data structure could be a list or a set, depending on what kind of operations you want; here, you want the operation `in` to be efficient, so a set would be more appropriate than a list. Thus I suggest to replace `l = (i**2 for i in range(10*4))` with `l = set(i**2 for i in range(10*4))` or equivalently `l = {i**2 for i in range(10*4)}`

Answer (score 0):

### Understanding generators

A list is a data structure: the elements in a list are stored in memory and can be looked at, modified, added or deleted at will.

By contrast, a generator is a [**lazy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) structure. The elements in a generator are *generated and consumed* when they are looked at. They are not generated sooner, and will not be regenerated later. Let's look at an example:

```py
# lists
>>> l = [i**2 for i in range(5)]
>>> l
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> l
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
>>> l
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16]

# generators
>>> g = (i**2 for i in range(5))
>>> g
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbec28e5970>
>>> next(g)
0
>>> next(g)
1
>>> next(g)
4
>>> list(g)
[9, 16]
>>> list(g)
[]
>>> list(g)
[]
```

Initially, `g` is ready to generate all elements `0,1,4,9,16`. But every element will only be generated once. Once we've seen the 0, and the 1, and the 4, we won't see them again. When we call `list(g)` after having already seen the first three elements, we get a list of only the last two elements. And if we try to call `list(g)` again after that, we get an empty list, because there are no elements left to generate.

In your code, you use the operator `in` to test whether an element is in a generator. Let's play with `in`:

```py
>>> g = (i**2 for i in range(5))
>>> 4 in g
True
>>> 9 in g
True
>>> 1 in g
False
>>> 16 in g
False
>>> 4 in g
False
```

What happened? First, `g` was ready to generate `0,1,4,9,16`. Then we asked whether `4 in g`? So the first three elements were generated, and `4` was found: we got the answer `True` and now `g` has only two elements left to generate. Then we ask: `9 in g`? One more element is generated, 9 is found, we get the answer `True` and now `g` only has one more element left to generate. Then we ask `1 in g`? Since there is no `1` left to generate, all elements remaining are generated, and `1` is not found. We get the answer `False` and now `g` is exhausted. Now, any question we ask will get the answer `False`: there is nothing left in `g`.

### Relevant documentation

I suggest reading [**the python tutorial, and its section on iterators and generators**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).